# Trying to obtain ServerCertificateValidation value for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method that I am trying to write a unit test for. I want to see that it returns true or false accordingly....a seemingly simple test that has me at a loss. See the note in the second code snippet to understand when the code gets run.

The code:

```
public void SetSSSPolicyFlag()
{
   if (_ignoreSSSPolicy)
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
   (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
}
```

The test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Ignore_SSPolicy_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    BaseController baseController = new BaseControllerBuilder()
                                    .WithSSSPolicy(true) //this executes the method above
                                    .Build();

   //Act
   var val = ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback;

   //Assert
   Assert.IsTrue(val.??);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your val is of type [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which means you want to call it with valid arguments.

```
   Assert.IsTrue(val(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors));
```

Since you are not using any of the arguments and you always return true in your implementation, you can set all arguments to dummy values:

```
   Assert.IsTrue(val(null, null, null, SslPolicyErrors.None));
```

Comment: Ohhh duh. Don't I feel dumb. Thanks